# Why google app engine is throwing server error

Tags: google-app-engine

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

My google appengine is throwing this error after deploy. When I tested it locally it was working fine. The versions were went higher than 15 but I deleted the older versions and now only 2 versions are there. But still I am getting the same error. What can I do to make my appengine works? Please help.

**Log**

```
{
    httpRequest: {"status":  500},
    insertId: "5a0ffcb500011a4129d76be9",
    labels: {
        clone_id: "00c61b117c7f4bcf62b687c18a5e5cfdc5dca0ce0d2548d2e5ea797a1dd1d0e4f55478a746f842"   
    },
    logName: "projects/xxxxxx/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log",
    operation: {
        first: true,
        id: "5a0ffcb200ff014bb267654c030001737e716f74692d37343133300001323031373131313874313433323033000100",
        last: true,
        producer: "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id",
    },
    protoPayload: {
        @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
        appEngineRelease:  "1.9.54",
        appId: "s~xxx-xxxxx", 
        endTime: "2017-11-18T09:26:12.345119Z",
        finished: true,
        first: true,
        host: "xxxx-xxxx.appspot.com",
        httpVersion:"HTTP/1.1",
        instanceId: "00c61b117c7f4bcf62b687c18a5e5cfdc5dca0ce0d2548d2e5ea797a1dd1d0e4f55478a746f842",
        instanceIndex:  -1,
        ip: "122.xxx.xx.xxx",
        latency: "2.260205s",
        method: "POST",
        pendingTime:  "2.237488746s",
        requestId:  "5a0ffcb200ff014bb267654c030001737e716f74692d37343133300001323031373131313874313433323033000100",
        resource:  "/reports/standardReport",
        startTime:  "2017-11-18T09:26:10.084914Z",
        status:  500,
        urlMapEntry:  "main.app",
        userAgent:  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36",
        versionId:  "20171118t143203",
    },
    receiveTimestamp:  "2017-11-18T09:26:13.075858035Z",
    resource: {
        labels: {
            module_id:  "default",
            project_id:  "xxxx-xxxx",
            version_id:  "20171118t143203",
            zone:  "us12",
        },
        type:  "gae_app",
    },
    timestamp:  "2017-11-18T09:26:10.084914Z",
}
```

[image]

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1.0
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest

default_expiration: "30d"

automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 1
  min_idle_instances: 1 # can be set to 0 for check
  max_concurrent_requests: 40 # can go upto 80
  min_pending_latency: 30ms #default value
```

Comment: Code and data are tested locally and are working perfect. And this is the only log available

Comment: Hm, highly suspect to get a 500 return code without an actual app error log. Check if you didn't miss it accidentally (it may be collapsed), see the image in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557680/reading-application-logs-on-google-app-engine-from-developer-console/43565578#43565578

Comment: @DanCornilescu I have added the screenshot also you can check there is no app error log. Let me add one more thing there is no instance running.

Comment: Standard env or flex?

Comment: standard env. I have app.yaml also

Comment: Things crossing my mind (mostly shots in the dark): the `api_version` value `1.0` is rather odd, can you pls change it to just `1` and re-deploy?;  is the version deployed the one receiving traffic? - check the versions page; something maybe not right in your app code - add the app code for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).