# How to check syslog in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-platform

I am using the standard environment of GAE / PY.
I'd like to confirm syslog, but I could not confirm it with stackdriver logging(only request_log and activity_log).

Can not you confirm syslog with App Engine standard environment?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to the actual `syslog` of the systems on top of which your standard env GAE app instances are running. I suspect the user-provided app code might not even have write permissions to such logfile.

If you're looking for logs produced by your app (for example by using the `logging` facility, as recommended by ), they're bundled under the `request_log` entries for the requests that triggered the respective code execution, see [Reading Application Logs on Google App Engine from Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557680/reading-application-logs-on-google-app-engine-from-developer-console/43565578#43565578)