# Can we enhance stackdriver's logging (Google AppEngine) (Python) (Standard)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I was wondering if anyone could hint out a way to modify / add data to the "RequestLog" object handled automatically by stackdriver for AppEngine standard environment. Or maybe Even publish independant full "RequestLogs" alongside the automated others ?

I m afraid we can just publish "ApplicationLogs" through python's built in logging library.

Thanks in advance for your answers / help.

Comment: No, you cannot modify/add request logs. But aren't app logs (attached to the respective request logs) sufficient for you? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer !

Actually a single request represents a batch of functions that are ran synchronously on the backend so error data or metrics are deeply burried inside a RequestLog ! I was looking for a way to bring to a higher level the important things happening inside the batch

Comment: @DanCornilescu ? (sorry for the ping)

Comment: I see. Well, they're just one level lower, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557680/reading-application-logs-on-google-app-engine-from-developer-console/43565578#43565578. And when you use log filtering the respective request logs will appear in the results even if just one of the contained app logs matches the filter.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was thinking more about later on when I will be setting up an "application deep performance monitoring system" when I will just be sending requests to a backend that will report me back the application health (error percentage per function / per batch / exec time / means ) etc..
Thank you for your answers anyway